# Can't remove a wine program after uninstalling wine

Tags: 18.04, wine, software-uninstall, photoshop

I have tried to download Photoshop in Wine and it worked. The problem is, that after I uninstalled wine Photoshop still appeared in my programs as in this screenshot:

[image: Image1]

Then, when I try to open it the following message appears:

[image: Image2]

```
Failed to change directory to "/home/nadav/.wine64/dosdevices C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2017" (no such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find ".desktop" file of photoshop, and remove it. Photoshop is removed with wine, but link to it still exists.

```
$ locate photoshop.desktop
```